# Which of these monomers can polymerize by chain addition reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

**Problem:**

Which of these monomers can polymerize by chain addition reaction?

[image]

**Solution:**

The monomers with red crosses underneath them can polymerize by chain addition reaction.

**Question:**

So, how I am thinking going about solving this problem is by using the definition for an addition reaction, which is when a molecule is added to another molecule on f.ex. its double bond and turning it into a single bond. I can see how that is possible for (i) and (ii), but how come the same doesn't apply to (iii) and (iv) where double bonds are also present? The method I'm thinking of obviously needs some tweaks, but maybe it should be scrapped entirely because it's not the intended method to use for these kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that those *active* sites are

- Carbon-carbon double-bonds
- Terminal
- Not in a ring, stabilized by resonance

Comment: Is a good rule of thumb then that the monomer should be unsaturated for it to polymerize by addition reaction?

Comment: A start, but not sufficient.